# Android External Authentication Using Asp.Net Web API 2.2

Tags: android, asp.net-identity, facebook-login

I am using ASP.NET WEB API 2.2 framework for my service layer. Individual accounts and external Facebook login features are enabled. And i try to use this restful service from my Android native application.

My first question is how can i use current authenticated facebook account at mobile device for my login mechanism. How can i get current logged in Facebook user and his/her datas like profile picture, finally send these datas to the restful service.

Second one is: if user is not authenticated in Facebook at his/her mobile device, should i redirect to Facebook login page. If yes, how can manage this workflow processes(open facebook user enters username and password, after logged in redirecting to my own native application, etc.).

In terms of service later(or web browser cookie authentication) there is no problem for Facebook authentication. However, there is lack of information, tutorials for Android Native Application login through Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Using Facebook Authentication in Android can be tackled by importing the Facebook SDK in our Android Project. After completing this import process, Facebook SDK now can supply access token.

However, there is not much enough tutorial, how can we use this Facebook access token for getting Owin bearer token from our ASP.NET WEB API 2.2 system.

In ASP.NET WEB API 2.2 template's apiaccountcontroller class there is lots of methods, how can we use them properly?